# image pinned to bottom of boxes

Tags: html, css

Please refer my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shalinid/mnwpo9wb/1/) location.

In my page, I want to maintain all boxes are in same height. So I used `display: table-cell;` in **box_left** div. I want to add shopping bag icon in each boxes. This shopping bag image is pinned to bottom of each boxes. But I couldn't. Please solve my problem.

My css is:

```
.box_left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

a img.shopping_bags{
    max-width:19px; 
    width:19px; 
    height:19px; 
    position:absolute; 
    margin:0px; 
    right:5px; 
    bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/mnwpo9wb/2/?

Comment: i tried and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnwpo9wb/3/)

```
.box_left {
   padding-bottom: 19px;
display: table-cell;
position: relative;
width: 170px;
background-color: !important;
border: 1px solid;
font-family: 'oswaldbook';
font-weight: normal;
}
a img.shopping_bags{ max-width:19px; width:19px; height:19px; position:absolute; margin:0px; right:5px; bottom:5px; }

.bags {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position:relative` to your `box-left` class. Also there is no `shopping_bags` in your HTML. So remove it in your CSS.

```
.box_left {
display: table-cell;
width: 170px;
background-color: !important;
border: 1px solid;
font-family: 'oswaldbook';
font-weight: normal;
position:relative;
}
a img{ max-width:19px; width:19px; height:19px; position:absolute; margin:0px; right:5px; bottom:5px; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/mnwpo9wb/4/)